# Hive JDBC Driver Python

Tags: python, jdbc, hive, jaydebeapi

I'm trying to connect to a Hive server with Jaydebeapi in python.

But I don't know which jar file I need to add to etablish my connection.

```
driver = 'org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver'
url_path = 'jdbc:hive2://link:port/db'
driver_arg ={'ssl':'*',
             'sslTrustStore':'*',
             'trustStorePassword':'*',
             'transportMode':'*',
             'httpPath':'*',
             'hive.tez.container.size':'*',
             'hive.tez.java.opts':'*'
            }

jarFile = [DIR + '']

conn_hive = jaydebeapi.connect(jclassname=driver,
                               url=url_path,
                               driver_args=driver_arg,
                               jars=jarFile
                              )
```

If you have any idea about which

Actually, I got this error :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundErrorPyRaisable: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hive/service/cli/thrift/TCLIService$Iface
```

If you have ideas or docs to share related to org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver and the jar.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I tried with : `hive-jdbc-3.1.2.jar`
But it's the same result

Comment: It looks like you are missing one or more dependencies. Check the documentation of the driver you're using.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to comment so I will drop this as an answer.The hive jar is known not to have all the necessary dependencies needed to connect to hive. I used this library [**hive-jdbc-uber-2.6.3.0-235.jar**](https://github.com/timveil/hive-jdbc-uber-jar/releases) instead with the below config

```
HIVE_CONFIG = {
    "jclassname":"org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver",
    "url": HIVE_URL,
    "driver_args": {"user": f'{HIVE_USER}', "password": f'{HIVE_PASSWORD}'},
    "jars": "../libs/hive-jdbc-uber-2.6.3.0-235.jar
    }
```

Comment: Didn't match my use case :/  .. I kept getting the "java.lang.RuntimeException: Class org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver not found" error